# For item in include

Tags: twig

I have the following code:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <div id="{{item.id}}" class="{{item.class}}">
        {% include '{{item.site}}' %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried with:

```
{% include 'item.site' %}
```

, during the generation I get the following:

```
[Twig_Error_Loader: Template "item.site" is not defined...
```

The structure when items are listed is good, because I delete the include and the generation is running perfectly.

How could I include sites this way? I have tabs in a site, and I whould like to include all tabs.

Thanks for the answers, 
Zoran

Comment: What's the value of item?

Comment: Simply try this `{% include item.site %}`

Comment: Thanks Matteo for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing any character in the statement as follow:

```
{% include item.site %}
```

Of course, the value must be a valid twig template path.

Hope this help